# Custom fetch event in Google's workbox library?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I'm using Google's Workbox library to cache files. I also want to roll my custom authentication using a service worker. So I read this guide on how to intercept requests and add headers: https://itnext.io/using-service-worker-as-an-auth-relay-5abc402878dd.

However, I'm wondering if this will mess up Workbox' logic? Should I place the authentication code below precacheAndRoute()? My static files cached through Workbox do not require my authentication headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "route" portion of Workbox's `precacheAndRoute()` respond to `fetch` events for URLs that are in the [precache manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list).

It will not do anything if the `fetch` event is associated with a URL that's not in the precache manifest. (I.e. it won't call `FetchEvent.respondWith()`, and other handlers will get a chance to respond.)

Adding your own custom logic in your own `fetch` event handler should play nicely with `precacheAndRoute()`.

(You might be able to get away with using Workbox's runtime caching for those requests that need authentication, along with a custom [`requestWillFetch` plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins) that adds in the headers before the network request is made. But that's up to you!)